Is the factorization method of Hamiltonian related to the theory of Lie groups?
I was learning about algebraic methods to solve the H atom, when I came across the factorization method. It is mentioned in various textbooks, notes and papers, like the one from Infeld and Hull.
I am familiar with ladder operators based on Lie groups and algebras, such as the (platitude) harmonic oscillator with $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, or the radial function of H atom with $\mathfrak{so}(2,1)$. However, the ladder-like factorization does not seem to be anything from, say, the $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ symmetry of the H atom, as they change the energy of states, while the realization of $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ (from the RLR vector, for instance) does not.
Question: Is the factorization method in any sense related to the theory of Lie groups and algebras? If not, does it admit some deeper mathematical background than merely a computational technique?

In this case it is not symmetry (described by Lie groups) but supersymmetry that accounts for the explicit solvability.
Indeed, the factorization method of Infeld an Hull is closely related to supersymmetric quantum mechanics. A good review of the relations is in the paper
Mustafa, M., & Kais, S. (2009). A Venn diagram for supersymmetric, exactly solvable, shape invariant, and Infeld-Hull factorizable potentials. arXiv:0911.4206.
